# adding keys to dict if condition is met, otherwise skip key if False

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a pythonic way to add a key to a dictionary if the condition is True, and just completely ignore it (skip) if it is false?

```
dict = {}

frame = scatter[x > y]
if frame.empty == False:
    dict[pct] = frame
else:
    None
```

I've tried writing:

```
dict[pct] = frame if frame.empty == False else None
```

But the problem here is that the "else None" adds a "None" value to the dictionary , and I need it to completely ignore/skip (not do anything) if else is activated.

Comment: Just remove the `else:
    None` part from the first code

Comment: but then I can't write it in 1 line , dict[pct] = frame if frame.empty == False raises an error

Comment: Note also that `x == False` is better written as `not x`.

Comment: shouldn't just: **if frame:** work?

Comment: @thomas.mac Just write it in two lines. You can't use a ternary operator because it just fundamentally has to evaluate to something. Having an extra line of code isn't a disaster.

Comment: @thomas.mac why must you write it on 1 line?

Comment: was just trying to write shorter / cleaner code, but I think I'll just remove the else statement

Comment: Shorter and cleaner are often very different goals IMHO.

Comment: cleaner != shorter

Comment: `frame.empty and dct.__setitem__(pct, frame)` is one non-pythonic way but I am just putting it here to make its relationship with the duplicate clearer.

Comment: @ayhan Wouldn't that be `not frame.empty`?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, my mistake. Thanks.